# Java - GMail API - Authorization code

Tags: java, google-oauth, gmail-api, google-api-java-client

I am trying the code below. The console prints out a URL which (after pasting in the address bar on my browser) sends me to google's user-consent page and asks for permission to access my account. It then redirects me to my html page - so far so good.

Now, I'm not sure if I receive a token or an authorization code. Where do I obtain it from? and then do I have to send an HTTP rest call from a web application to go along with the Gmail API request, or can I do it via JAVA?

```
public class People {
  public void setUp() throws IOException {
        HttpTransport httpTransport = new NetHttpTransport();
        JacksonFactory jsonFactory = new JacksonFactory();

        String clientId = "client_id";
        String clientSecret = "secret";

        String redirectUrl = "http://localhost:8080/TestingGmailMail/webapps/login.html";
        String scope = "https://www.googleapis.com/auth/contacts.readonly";


        String authorizationUrl = new GoogleBrowserClientRequestUrl(clientId,redirectUrl,Arrays.asList(scope)).build();


        // Point or redirect your user to the authorizationUrl.
        System.out.println("Go to the following link in your browser:");
        System.out.println(authorizationUrl);
        }
}
```

Comment: I am not a java expert but the client library should be handling it all for you have you tried reading this tutorial?  https://developers.google.com/gmail/api/quickstart/java#prerequisites

Comment: Thank a lot - DalmTo! Yes, I have tried reading it and find it terribly obtuse.. I'll try going over the library tho

Comment: Its very confusing when you start using Google APIs.   I cant help with java but maybe I can help guide you a little. GoogleAuthorizationCodeFlow handles requesting auth from the user and it saves the authentication (no idea where in java) should be refreshtoken and an access token.    getGmailService will give you access to access the API it will fetch a new access token when and if it needs one.  Everything you do will be though the GmailService

Answer (score 0):

Yes, @DalmTo is correct in pointing out that the client library is the one that should be handling all this.

A better design is to store user credentials for your application in a directory.

```
private static final java.io.File DATA_STORE_DIR = new java.io.File(
    System.getProperty("user.home"), ".store/mail_credentials");
```

Now, make a global instance for `FileDataStoreFactory`.

```
private static FileDataStoreFactory DATA_STORE_FACTORY;
```

Instantiate `DATA_STORE_FACTORY` before getting credentials preferably in a static block.

```
DATA_STORE_FACTORY = new FileDataStoreFactory(DATA_STORE_DIR);
```

Download and store the `client_secret.json` from Google Developer console. Use the following method to get credentials:

```
public static Credential authorize() throws IOException {
    // Load client secrets.
    InputStream in
            = GmailQuickStart.class.getResourceAsStream("/client_secrets.json");
    GoogleClientSecrets clientSecrets
            = GoogleClientSecrets.load(JSON_FACTORY, new InputStreamReader(in));

    // Build flow and trigger user authorization request.
    GoogleAuthorizationCodeFlow flow
            = new GoogleAuthorizationCodeFlow.Builder(
                    HTTP_TRANSPORT, JSON_FACTORY, clientSecrets, SCOPES)
            .setDataStoreFactory(DATA_STORE_FACTORY)
            .setAccessType("offline")
            .build();
    Credential credential = new AuthorizationCodeInstalledApp(
            flow, new LocalServerReceiver()).authorize("user");
    System.out.println(
            "Credentials saved to " + DATA_STORE_DIR.getAbsolutePath());
    return credential;
}
```

Whenever the above method is called, it looks for the `StoredCredential` in the path provided to `DATA_STORE_DIR`. If it is found, then the code executes as is. If not, a browser will open which will ask you to login and authorize your app. The credentials generated as such will be stored in the `DATA_STORE_DIR` location. As long as the `StoredCredential` is present, your app won't ask for permission. This is a general purpose design which can be also used for other Google APIs.